# Where should I go for online information on animals endemic specifically in Mozambique?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ecology, literature, species

I've been involved with the citizen science project "Wildcam Gorongosa" for over half a year now ([website](http://www.wildcamgorongosa.org), [forum](http://www.zooniverse.org/projects/zooniverse/wildcam-gorongosa/talk)). As there are lots of unexperienced volunteers, many questions are being asked. Often I'd like to answer, but also not having a biology background I usually have to do some research first to give an accurate answer. For this reason, I'm looking for informative, up-to-date online resources, like e.g. search engines, animal guides etc.

I have come across a few websites that give some information on animals in the whole of Africa (e.g. [ultimateungulate.com](http://www.ultimateungulate.com)) - but I wonder if there are more suitable places to go if I'm specifically looking for animals in Mozambique (or even Gorongosa National Park). I'm still relatively new to the topic - where would a scientist involved with research on Mozambican ecology go and look for this kind of "specific" information? As the project deals with pictures taken by wildlife cameras, I am only interested in animals of a certain size (I guess rat-sized and larger). I'd be happy to find e.g. more information on the appearance of each species, its geographic distribution, their respective habitats and their general behavior.

I realize that this question is somewhat broad - please do ask ahead, I'll try to add details if necessary!

Answer (score 2):

1. [Here](http://www.listofcountriesoftheworld.com/mz-animals.html) is a large list of animals (sorted by guilds) that can be found throughout Mozambique.

   - Each animal in the list is linked to a page with picture and information!
2. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildlife_of_Mozambique) maintains a few lists of animals found in Mozambique.

   - See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mammals_of_Mozambique) for  a list of mammals (sorted by order).
   - See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_birds_of_Mozambique) for a list of birds (sorted by order).
   - They also have 2 lists for mollusks ([fresh-water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_non-marine_molluscs_of_Mozambique), [marine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_marine_molluscs_of_Mozambique)) and 1 for [plants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Flora_of_Mozambique).
3. Gorongosa's own website provides a list of common animals found in Gorongosa:
   http://www.gorongosa.org/explore-park/wildlife
4. As user Sudachi mentioned in a comment below,  [iNaturalist](http://inaturalist.org/places/mozambique) and [GBIF](http://gbif.org/country/MZ/summary) also have lots of well-managed species lists and observation data.

Comment: I'd also like to add a few resources. [iNaturalist](http://inaturalist.org/places/mozambique) and [GBIF](http://gbif.org/country/MZ/summary) also have lots of well-managed species lists and observation data.